# How can i install open neubula on ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, opennebula

I am try to installing open nebula cloud environment on my Ubuntu 14.04.Its showing some packages error.I don't know exactly what kind of error occurs.
An Error is below:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     opennebula : Depends: opennebula-tools (= 3.4.1-4.1ubuntu1) but 4.6.2-1 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please some help me for installing open stack in my system.Otherwise alternate way is there?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
aptitude install opennebula
```

if you dont have install aptitude, solved:

```
apt-get install aptitude
```